# ModSecurity default action when no rule is match?

Tags: web-application-firewall, mod-security2

I'm lab with modSecurity using nginx, I have a question

How can you set default action for actione doesn't match anyrule

For example I have set of rule allow people do stuff form 1 set of IP, I want to block all other request?
How caN I do that ?

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat

SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "phase:1,chain,id:10,allow,log,msg:'Blocking Country IP Address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@pm CN"

SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,drop,status:403,tag:'SLA 24/7'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny all requests which didn't matched with any rules before, you have to create an explicit unconditional rule (`SecAction`) at the end of set of your rules, something like this:

```
SecAction "id:10001,phase:1,deny,status:403,log"
```

Please note, that with this solution (rule in `phase:1`) you can't use any other phase. Of course, you should put this rule into `phase:2`, but without any rule in that phase, it's enough.

More notes for your example:

- your action is `allow` but the message is ***Blocking** Country IP Address*, this is a bit confusing
- if you want to control only the access/not access by country, there is a standalone [Nginx module](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module), you don't need any WAF